# Grid Columns data overlapping in semantic-ui-react?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

https://codesandbox.io/s/m3ljr4zl8p

`example.js`

I wasn't expecting column1 data to start overlapping into column2's instead of going down as it is now exceeding the grid column width.

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns are not overlapping. It's your `<p>` element takes more space than columns.

Add this style to it:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Before `word-break`:

[image: before]

After `word-break`:

[image: after]

Comment: But if I had used simple css grids. This wouldn't be happening, right?!

Comment: @Shad that would happen in any scenario. You used long word, if you don’t want it to go over it’s parent break the word or use overflow: hidden. As you saw on my screenshots your grid was always good